# Response time analysis for rm

Tags: rate

I learned operating system in collage
so i studied response time for rm

```
for (int k = 0; k < pInfo.tasks.size(); k++)
        {
            Task task_k = pInfo.tasks.get(k);
            int sum = 0;
            double interval = task_k.execTime;
            while (interval< task_k.Deadline)
            {
                sum = (int)task_k.execTime;
                for (int i = 0; i < pInfo.tasks.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (i<k)
                    {
                        Task task_i = pInfo.tasks.get(i);
                        sum += Math.ceil(interval/task_i.Period)*task_i.execTime;
                    }
                }
                if(interval == sum)
                    break;
                else
                    interval = sum;
            }
            if (interval>task_k.Deadline)
                return 0;
            else if(interval == sum)
            {

            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

i don't know how to write in else if

I tried just continue
and if(k>=pInfo.tasks.size()) return 1;

but everything is not answer